# Revalue strings in a column using regular expression in Python

Tags: python, regex

I have a dataset with a column value :

```
0      TCGA-A2-A0T2
1      TCGA-A2-A0CM
2      TCGA-BH-A18V
3      TCGA-BH-A18Q
4      TCGA-BH-A0E0
```

However, I want to change it to:

```
A0T2
A0CM
A18V
A18Q
A0E0
```

I have tried code such as

```
df1['Complete TCGA ID'].str.extract('TCAG-(.*)-.*')
```

But it only returns NA. I really don't know how to figure out regular expression in this case. Can anyone please help? Thanks so much in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for

```
df1['new_column'] = df1['Complete TCGA ID'].str.extract(r'-([^-]+)$')
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/WYWkRC/1).

Answer (score 2):

It should be TCGA instead, and you can match till the last - and then capture the rest in group 1.

```
TCGA.*-(.*)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/SnDAUJ/1)

Or a bit more precise match for the example data:

```
^TCGA-[A-Z0-9]+-([A-Z0-9]+)$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/RKvZcn/1)